# How to generate alphabet slice

Tags: go

I'm trying to generate an alphabet slice.

This is all I have so far

```
    letters := []string{}
    alphabet := []string{}
    for i := 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++ {
        alphabet := append(letters, "a")
    }
    fmt.Println(alphabet)
```

This doesn't work. Can someone help me out?

Comment: This does not even compile. Error "alphabet declared but not used".

Answer (score 2):

With `alphabet := append(letters, string(i))`, you are creating a new object every time due to `:` and the outer one is not used.

```
alphabet := []string{}
for i := 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++ {
    alphabet = append(alphabet, string(i))
}
fmt.Println(alphabet)
```

Also, you don't need `letters` object as you can append on the `alphabet` as you go along and assign the returned object to itself.

---

Update: I agree with @shmsr that using `string` slice is an overkill if you just want to store a byte of data so you can use `byte` slice as:

```
alphabet := []byte{}
var i byte
for i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++ {
    alphabet = append(alphabet, i)
}
fmt.Println(string(alphabet)) // need explicit type conversion though else it prints ascii values by default
```

Note: You need an explicit type conversion though otherwise it prints ascii values by default.

Comment: Don't use a string of holding a 1-byte character.

Answer (score 1):

Your program has some bugs because of which you're not getting the desired output. I've added comments to your code so that you can have a basic idea of where are you doing it incorrectly.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    // we don't really need the two slice
    letters := []string{}
    alphabet := []string{}
    for i := 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++ {
        // alphabet declared but not used (compile error)
        alphabet := append(letters, "a") // why hard-code "a"? wrong!
    }
    // print a slice of string? wrong!
    // each character could be stored in byte or rune and then the slice could
    // converted to string
    fmt.Println(alphabet)
}
```

The following code might help:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    // Pre-allocate slice for storing 26 letters
    // Note: Instead of []byte, we can use []rune as well
    // But as our scope is limited to storing 'A' to 'Z' only
    // byte is enought to hold each letter.
    alphabet := make([]byte, 0, 26)

    // Loop over 'A' to 'Z' and keep on appending
    // to alphabet slice
    var ch byte
    for ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ch++ {
        alphabet = append(alphabet, ch)
    }

    // Print alphabet
    fmt.Println(string(alphabet))
}
```

Comment: Why are we storing in bytes? Why not just store strings?

Comment: You can use rune as well. Or even byte. Or in fact, even strings. But the thing is that 'A' to 'Z' takes up on 1 byte in memory i.e., `uint8` in Go.

Comment: Also, when you do `for i := 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++ { ... }`, shorthand assignment makes the type of `i` as `rune`. So if you don't do any typecasting, you can directly append it to a slice of rune.